# IIS URL rewrite does not seem to even evaluate

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-8.5

I have a URL rewrite in place and I tested the pattern.  In the test it says it matches but when I try the website it does nothing.  It just goes to the existing site.

```
<rule name="matchAll" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="https\://dev\.oldwebsite\.net" />
    <conditions>
       <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="https\://dev\.oldwebsite\.net/application\.php" negate="true" />
       <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="https\://dev\.newwebsite\.com" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://dev.newwebsite.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

**New development:**  I was able to get some of the redirect to work with the following.  but the {PATH_INFO} is not working.

```
<rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="RedirectAll" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="dev.olddomain.net" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://dev.newdomain.com" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="application\.php" negate="true" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="dev\.newdomain\.com" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
    </rule>
</rules>
```

**Latest Test Tuesday 9:59pm**

```
<rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="application.php exclusion" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="application.php" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^dev\.olddomain\.net$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="None" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="RedirectAll" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="dev\.newdomain\.com" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://dev.newdomain.com" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Comment: I want to redirect everything EXCEPT a single application

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59 Mistake 1.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I tried to modify my rules to resemble what you linked.  (Nice blog by the way...)